# Having issue with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

What I want to do is following.

Lets say we have array like that

```
$arr=array();
$arr[1]['test1']="something";
$arr[1]['test2']="something else"
```

...

```
$arr[2]['test1']="blah blah";
$arr[2]['test2']="foo bar"
```

...

I want to echo them one by one like that

```
something   something else ... <all elements of $arr[1]>

blah blah  foo bar         ... <all elements of $arr[2]>
```

BUT!

```
if($arr[1]['test1']=="something")
don't echo elements of $arr[1] at all
```

Is that possible by new array creation in which $arr[1] doesn't exist at all? Or during echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should do the trick:

```
// Iterate and show the words
foreach ($arr as $words) {
    if (in_array("something", $words))
        continue;

    echo join(' ', $words) . '<br />';
}
```

The `continue` call will jump to the next iteration, so it will skip the array if it contains the "something" element

Comment: Read carefully question. I know what does mean implode, but implode has nothing  to do with my question

Comment: And what if I don't know in which array exactly located "something" (I mean in $arr[1]['test1'] or ... $arr[n]['test1'])? How do I find and unset right array?

Comment: @epic_syntax - Please check again ;)

Comment: continue? I told ya, unset parent array in which "something" located

Comment: Maybe you should improve your question... Give a look at http://php.net/array_filter

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, but please be more specific,if it is not what you mean.
do you want to check only the first element of $arr[1] if it is "something"? Do you know all keys of the array?
Or: Could we loop through the whole array first and after delete some elements?

```
$arr=array();
$arr[1]['test1']="something";
$arr[1]['test2']=" something else1 ";
$arr[1]['test3']=" something else2 ";

$arr[2]['test1']=" abc ";
$arr[2]['test2']=" def ";
$arr[2]['test3']=" ghi ";


foreach ($arr as $sub_arr){
    if($sub_arr['test1']!="something"){
        foreach ($sub_arr as $element){
            echo $element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I don't know in which array exactly located "something" (I mean in $arr[1]['test1'] or ... $arr[n]['test1'])? How do I find and unset right array?

Comment: As long as you know that it is "$arr[n][test1]", my code should work for you. Just change die 1<->2 of the array above and see that is still displays "abc def ghi"

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr[1] as $value){
    if($value == "something"){
        unset($arr[1]);
    }
}
sort($arr);
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
    echo implode(" ",$arr[$i]);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

this will unset array with something value
then sort will happened  and display it as you want it

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through and add logic inside.

```
$new=array();
$omit = -1;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($value['test1']=="something"){            
       $omit = $key;
    }else{
       $new[$key] = $value['test1'].' '.$value['test2'];
    }
    if(isset($new[$omit])){
     unset($new[$omit]);
    }
}

//now print the final array one by one
foreach($new as $final){
   echo $final.'<br/>';
}
```